# MacBook Pro (late 2013) drops connection to wireless router every 15 minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, wifi, router

My MacBook Pro is a late 2013 edition model, running OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. Every 15 minutes (the intervals are very regular) it loses connection to my router; pings to the router do not go through, but the WiFi icon does not turn grey. After a minute or so the connection reappears.

I've had this problem for about a year; I guess since the OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 update. I've tried the first solution from [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/25/fix-wi-fi-problems-os-x-yosemite/) (removing network configuration files) multiple times, it helps for several weeks but then the problem comes back.

1. No other device has this problem (two laptops with Windows, Windows phone, Android tablets/phone)
2. This problem only happens with the router I have at home.
3. The 15 minute interval is given by the laptop – it is very stable but the starting point changes when the laptop goes to and back from sleep.
4. There are three-four other WiFi networks with strong signal (all protected, none is at the same channel)
5. Network configuration is set to `Automatic`, there are two “Unknown” locations

Any ideas what may cause it?

Comment: I suggest you to start by: create a new "network configuration" with just the Wi-Fi interface which is "active" and on "your" Wi-Fi network. If you don't need Bluetooth turn it off. If you are using the 802.11b channels (1 - 14) choose a channel which is as far as possible from all your neighboors Wi-Fi channels (ideally 3 channels should always separate you & your neighboors).

Comment: The link you used from osxdaily.com is containing some dangerous pieces of advice (notably playing with the normal DNS servers and the MTU parameter). And there isn't the smallest explanation why to make such risky manipulations.

Comment: Read this answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98695/22003 . And once `Wireless Diagnostics` is running, select `Window > Utilities > Performance`.