# Degraded wireless performance on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, performance

I have a Mid-2013 MacBook Air that has been acting up lately. I initially started seeing issues with ridiculous jitter(100s of ms) half a year ago, but since I do not game a lot, I ignored them. However, for the past few months, I've started seeing more and more degraded WiFi performance on my Air.

For instance, if I run speedtests within seconds of each other(after the first one has completed) on my Mac and on my phone, I get ~3x higher ping, 4x slower download, and about the same or better upload speeds(which I think is a limitation with my phone).

I have tried doing an SMC reset, deleting the following files:

- com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
- com.apple.network.identification.plist
- com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
- NetworkInterfaces.plist
- preferences.plist

from the `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` directory, as was suggested by a guide named `Fix Wi-Fi Problems in OS X Yosemite` on osxdaily. None of these showed any improvement for me. I have a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter, and when I use that, I see the speeds like they should be.

I suspect this is some issue with my wireless card, unless its a problem with OS X itself, which is kinda likely given that I am using `10.11 Beta (15A215h)`, but the issue has been present even before I upgraded to the Beta OS. Does anyone have any ideas of what the issue could be, and how I could resolve it myself?

EDIT:

[Screen cap of Network](http://prntscr.com/8jvi7b)

Clients are an average of 4, sometimes more, sometimes less

[Screen cap of performance test with only the Air connected to the network](http://prntscr.com/8jvjty)

Also, I've tried with different routers, with only my Air connected, and I ALWAYS see the performance degradation, no matter what network I connect to.

Comment: This question is very similar to this previous one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/206481/22003 . Please read my 3 comments. If you provide more technical information with your question, yours will win an answer first.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Honestly, I do not see the similarity. My connection does not drop, I face the issue with any network I connect to, the issue is constant and does not appear with an interval, and I can be sitting next to the router with no other networks, and the issue persists. [this](http://prntscr.com/8jotyp) is what my performance graph from wireless diagnostics looks like.

Comment: You followed a web page on osxdaily which is of technical very low quality and dangerous. Could you please include a screen capture of: `System Preferences > Network`? Could you add in your original question the number of clients within your wireless network? Could you run your performance test with all your equipments but your MacBook Air turned off, and provide the results?

Comment: @danielAzuelos I've added the additional information that you requested.

Comment: Nik, have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @AntonTarasenko The issue no longer exists for me. I cannot pinpoint how it got resolved, since it's been two years, but I suspect my routers, since I didn't need to change the wireless card.